# Why won't this simple 'if' statement work (inside fast enumeration)?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, if-statement, fast-enumeration

I am enumerating through the `ChecklistItem` entities in my table to see which ones have a `priority` (NSNumber attribute) of 1. `checklistItems` are in a to-many relationship with `Checklist`.

In this simple code, the first NSLog works fine, and reports that several of my ChecklistItems have a priority of 1. But the second NSLog never gets called. Why is this? I assume I'm framing the "if" statement wrong, but I don't know how.

```
for (ChecklistItem *eachItem in checklist.checklistItems){
    NSLog(@"Going through loop. Item %@ has priority %@.", eachItem.name, eachItem.priority);

    if (eachItem.priority == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]) {
        NSLog(@"Item %@ has priority 1", eachItem.name);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not compare objects as you did above. Use the following code.

```
for (ChecklistItem *eachItem in checklist.checklistItems){
    NSLog(@"Going through loop. Item %@ has priority %@.", eachItem.name, eachItem.priority);

    if ([eachItem.priority intValue]== 1) {
        NSLog(@"Item %@ has priority 1", eachItem.name);
        }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: But I have read that NSNumber has - (int)intValue method? Is there something wrong in documentation?please mention.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing the pointers of the return values of `eachItem.priority` and `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]`. You should use `NSNumber`'s equality method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should be checking for value equality something like this:

```
if ( [eachItem.priority intValue] == 1 ) { ... }
```

However, I'm kind of surprised it doesn't *accidentally* work as it is, because I thought `NSNumber` pooled a few base instances and I'd expect 1 to be one of them. Relying on that would be very bad form, though, even if it happened to work in this case.